# pfsense mount root error after disk clone

Tags: pfsense

I went the lazy route and cloned my SSD that runs my current pfsense (2.1.5) machine to create a backup machine with the same config.
Instead of doing a fresh reinstall and copying the config.

Both machines have the exact same hardware and BIOS settings.
Both SSD's I used, main and clone are the same (size and brand).

I used clonezilla to create the clone.

During the boot of my "backup" machine I got the error:

http://puu.sh/p2Ppc/edd7d0d38c.jpg

Trying to mount root from ufs:/dev/ad4s1a
ROOT MOUNT ERROR

Following the ?:
http://puu.sh/p2PDm/7877dbf8cf.jpg

It's so weird that this happend as it was a 1:1 clone.
Also /dev/ad4s1a exists

Anyone have any ideas how to:
 1. Solve my current problem?
 2. Avoid this during a clone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know if you hit the ? it will list the drives and you can then tell it by ufs:/dev/ad4s1a (if that is where pfsense is) .. Once that works and boots you can then edit a file and update that to what you found is boot point.  I am right now trying find the file to change